Make "git diff" output a remark when there is no difference
When the two commits are the same, git diff generates no result.
However, is there a way to make it output some text, such as "no difference in commit1 and commit2"? this is to help identify the result in script log.

If you call it in Bash, catch the Return Code and echo the Output you want

"--exit-code Make the program exit with codes similar to diff(1). That is, it exits with 1 if there were differences and 0 means no differences." git diff documentation. Are you running git on Linux?

@ÁlvaroGonzález I'm running it in Windows GIT Bash. I've tried that but it's also silent.

In Unix/Linux shells you can use exit code to decide whether to print an additional message, but you need to ask git diff to generate it:

--exit-code
Make the program exit with codes similar to diff(1). That is, it exits with 1 if there were differences and 0 means no differences.

git diff --exit-code && echo no difference in commit1 and commit2

If you want to type it often, you'll probably want to create an alias or function.

You could use the --name-only option to list the files that have changed between the two compared objects, and then pipe the result to wc --lines to count the number of lines (files) that are different.
If there is no difference, it won't print a specific message like you wanted, but it will at least print a 0, showing some type of output.
git diff --name-only HEAD~ HEAD | wc --lines

Also, if you wish not to type this lengthy command at each use, you could define an alias:
# define the alias locally in your repo
git config --local alias.my-diff '!sh -c "git diff --name-only $1 $2 | wc --lines"'

# invoking the alias
git my-diff HEAD~ HEAD

